# Why can I insert a custom element into ckeditor without modifing the schema

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

When I use the following javascript code, a custom node is inserted into the model. But I don't understand why this works when that type(mtnote) have not been registered with the schema.

```
    model.change(writer => {
        const noteElement=writer.createElement('mtnote',{ 'noteText': 'Hello first note' } );
                const insertNotePos=model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
                writer.append(noteElement,insertNotePos);
});
```

I know that the node is inserted, because I can see it when I iterate over the model, and if I add a editor.conversion.for('downcast') I can downcast the mtnote element to any view element I wish.

So is writer.append not checking the schema, or have I misunderstood what the schema should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right – **[`Writer`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html) does not check the schema.**

The reason for that is that it's a pretty low-level tool which implements way to perform atomic operations on the model (OK, I'm lying here, because there's an even lower level underneath, represented by [operations](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_operation_operation-Operation.html) themselves, but that's a protected API). Anyway, the writer is pretty low-level.

Now, when you implement a command or any other feature you may need to perform multiple operations to do all the necessary changes. The state in the meantime (between these atomic operations) may be incorrect. The writer must allow that.

For instance, you need to move `<foo>` from `<$root>` to `<bar>` and (at the same time) rename it to `<oof>`. But the schema defines that `<oof>` is not allowed in `<$root>` and `<foo>` in `<bar>`. If the writer would check schema it'd complain regardless of the order of `rename` and `move` operations.

But let's say this we could solve by checking the schema at the end of a [`change()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-change) block (it works like a transaction – the state needs to be  correct at the end of it). In fact, we [plan to strip disallowed attributes](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/issues/1228) at the end of that blocks.

There are problems, though:

- How to fix the content after a transaction is committed? It's impossible to implement a reasonable heuristic that wouldn't break the content from the user's perspective.
- The model can become invalid during collaborative changes. Operational Transformation, while implemented by us in a very rich form (with 11 types of operations instead of the base 3) ensures conflict resolution and eventual consistency, but not model's validity.

Therefore, we chose to handle such situations per case, using more expressive and flexible [post fixers](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-registerPostFixer). Additionally, we moved the responsibility to check the schema to features. They can make a lot better decisions apriori, before doing changes.